# Writing a proper sentence as a honor in a CV

Tags: american-english

Assume a student reaches rank 10 among 20 students in a final competition. The competition composes several steps and the initial number of participants is about 300,000, but only the first best 20 students are selected.
If this student wants to add this honor in his/her CV, what sentence properly describes this honor? 
For example, these two following are my suggestions:
1) Ranked in top 20 students in Competition X (competition name is placed at X)

2) Ranked among the top 20 students in Competition X.

Comment: I'd think tenth out of 300,000 is much better positioning.

Comment: @Jim What if we dont want to mention that 300,000?

Comment: Then you are one of the top ***10*** students in the competition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my suggestion, especially if you don't want to specify the number of participants.

Format [verbose]: 
Ranked in the top [X% of] [scale] [category] [type of contest], [name of contest].

Example:
Ranked in the top 0.1% of the national robotic engineering team competition, robolympics 2019.

Format [concise]: 
Ranked in the top [X% of] [category] [type of contest], [name of contest].

Example:
Ranked in the top 0.1% of the robotics competition, robolympics 2019.